# Assigning task to referenced user

Tags: custom-field, tasks

I want to set up a process to assign a task to an opportunity field of type Lookup(User). When I try to trigger the process I get the following error:

"This record couldn't be saved because it failed to trigger a flow(...)"

And an email with further details:

```
RECORD CREATE: myRule_4_A1<br>
Create one Task record where:<br>
ActivityDate = {!myVariable_current.Survey_Scheduled__c} (May 17, 2016)<br>
OwnerId = {!myVariable_current.Prelim_OA__c} (003o000000WSdhWAAT)<br>
Priority = Normal<br>
Status = Open<br>
Subject = Generate Proposal<br>
WhatId = {!myVariable_current.Id} (006o0000009grQ1AAI)<br>
Result<br>
Failed to create record.<br>
Error Occurred: INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION) Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: 003o000000WSdhWAAT,<br>
```

It looks like the Prelim_OA field is of the wrong data type, but I've tried Lookup(User) and Lookup(Contact), neither works. Another thing I noticed is that other processes that assign tasks, the Assigned To strings take you to the user page when pasted at the end of salesforce.com and the prelim_OA value takes you to a contact page. Not sure if this is significant.

What data type would be needed to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

OwnerId field takes user record id values. What you are assigning here is a contact i think. this probably is causing the issue. You can assign contact record id to the task field whoid and user record id to the task field ownerid.

Comment: So if I go to Setup > Build > Customize > Opportunities > Fields, create a new field, where would I find user record ID? I see Lookup(User), but not Lookup(User record ID).

Comment: Actually i wasn't saying to create a new field. But rather assign the user's record-id to the field owner id. You can find the user's record id from the url , when you view the user record. So in your flow  the current value {!myVariable_current.Prelim_OA__c}, i assume Prelim_OA__c is a lookup to contact. You need to have a similar field which has user's id to whom the task has to be assigned. Or get the task owner's (user record id) id dynamically in the flow.

Comment: Ok. Then Prelim_OA needs to be a lookup(user) and not lookup(contact). A contact's id cannot be assigned to the Task OwnerId field. It only accepts User record id's.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as I mentioned in the original question, I've tried Lookup(User) and Lookup(Contact), each generated similar errors.

Comment: No problem. Can you post the error which you get when you try with lookup(user). My assumption is - it should work without an issue. But there could be a different reason why you are getting the error.